# Difference between audio frameworks on linphone audio settings

Tags: android, audio, linphone, opensl

I am looking at the linphone audio settings and I see that there're two audio frameworks available, which is the difference between using **AAaudio** framework or **OpenSL**?

The other item that appears in the list is **Android SND** and says that it is **deprecated**, but with this option is how the microphone behaves better in calls, why?

[image]

With this I would like to know if it influences the fact of using one framework or another since I am having echo and microphone sensitivity problems in the calls I make with my device (Zebra TC21 with android 10) using linphone.

Help :(

Thanks

Comment: Check this question for answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43754910/aaudio-or-opensl

Comment: @DilyanAtanasov, I have seen that answer before but thank you very much anyway, from what I see, in the answer recommend the oboe framework, but I don't know if using one or the other can solve the echo problems we are having in communications, how it affects the behavior of the microphone of the device?